# Example of sequence $\{f_n\}$ of $\mathcal C([a,b],\mathbb R)$ that is equicontinuous that has not a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone provide an example of equicontinuous sequence $(f_n)_n$ of $\mathcal C^0([a,b],\mathbb R)$ that is equicontinuous but has no convergent subsequence ? I was thinking to $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ on $[0,1]$ but it's not equicontinuous and is convergent.

Comment: Not equicontinuous? Why do you think that?

Comment: Please clarify what space you are considering . Why is there a superscript $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $(f_n)$ with $f_n(x)=n$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. It is equicontinuous but has no converging subsequence.

Comment: This applies only to the question in the title. But for continuous functions vanishing at $0$ this example does not work.

Comment: For sure it's equicontinuous!  Each function is constant. You are not using the right definition for equicontinuous. Please have a look at the definition.

Comment: @user657324 : For a function family to be equally continuous in all its elements has nothing to do with it being a Cauchy sequence or any other convergence property.